# post_parent in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, post-type

I've two custom post types, `type1` and `type2`

My current workflow of creating contents, from the user perspective

- a user created posts of `type1`, i.e. `post1`, `post2`, `post3` on a particular day
- our system automatic create a post of `type2` is at the end of the day, i.e. `post
- the `post_parent` of `post1`, `post2`, `post3` are set to `post4`

So, there are two cases:

- How to auto reset the `post_parent` of `post1`, `post2`, `post3` when `post4` is deleted? (I want to retain `post1`, `post2`, `post3`)
- How to auto delete `post1`, `post2`, `post3` when `post4` is deleted? (I want cleanup)

Answer (score 2):

Hook in when a post is deleted, check for the post type, then manipulate `post_parent` of potential child posts (or delete the posts):

```
function wp_dev_174635_update_posts( $parent_id ) {

    $parent = get_post( $parent_id );
    if ( $parent->post_type !== 'type2' ) {
        return;
    }

    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'   => 'type1',
        'post_parent' => $parent_id,
    ) );
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        // EITHER: Reset post parent entry
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'          => $post->ID,
            'post_parent' => 0,
        ) );

        // OR: Delete post
        // wp_delete_post( $post->ID );
    }
}

add_action( 'delete_post', 'wp_dev_174635_update_posts' );
```